Equation yielding less solutions through this method: $\frac{1 - x^{2}}{1 + x^{2}} = \sqrt{1 - x^{2}}$
This may seem a very childish equation yet I am very baffled with this.
Solutions of the equation:
$\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}=\sqrt{1-x^2}$

My approach:
$\implies \frac{1-x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=1+x^2$
$\implies \sqrt{1-x^2}=1+x^2$
$\implies 1-x^2=(1+x^2)^2$
$\implies 1-x^2=1+x^4+2x^2$
$\implies x^4+3x^2=0$
$\implies x^2(x^2+3)=0$
$\therefore x=0$
But the actual answer is $\boxed{x=0,1,-1}$
Where have I gone wrong with my method which reduces my solutions?

Your first step is only valid if division by $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ is not division by zero.  Is there/are there values of $x$ that make $\sqrt{1-x^2} = 0$ that also solve the original equation?

When dividing by $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ you assume it is not equal to zero, thus excluding $±1$ from the values of $x$, and you "lose" the solutions $x= ±1$.

HINT
Since $|x|\leq 1$, one may consider that $x = \sin(\theta)$. Consequently, it results that
\begin{align*}
\frac{1 - x^{2}}{1 + x^{2}} = \sqrt{1 - x^{2}} & \Longleftrightarrow \frac{\cos^{2}(\theta)}{1 + \sin^{2}(\theta)} = |\cos(\theta)|\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \frac{\cos^{4}(\theta)}{(1 + \sin^{2}(\theta))^{2}} = \cos^{2}(\theta)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \cos^{4}(\theta) = \cos^{2}(\theta)(1 + \sin^{2}(\theta))^{2}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \cos^{2}(\theta)(\cos^{2}(\theta) - 1 - 2\sin^{2}(\theta) - \sin^{4}(\theta)) = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \cos^{2}(\theta)(3\sin^{2}(\theta) + \sin^{4}(\theta)) = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \sin^{2}(\theta)\cos^{2}(\theta)(3 + \sin^{2}(\theta)) = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \sin(2\theta) = 0
\end{align*}
Can you take it from here?

Do you think that $\sin2\theta=0$ is an easier equation? Nice play with trigonometric functions tough.

Most students will miss $k=3$ case, since sine has period $2\pi.$ Hence, they will not find the root $-1.$ @Atila Correia

Correct way without "losing" some solutions:
By inner and outer multiplication,
$$1-x^2=\sqrt{1-x^2}(1+x^2)$$
Squaring,
$$(1-x^2)^2=(1-x^2)(1+x^2)^2$$
Collecting to the right side,
$$(1-x^2)(1+x^2)^2-(1-x^2)^2=0$$
Factoring,
$$(1-x^2)[(1+x^2)^2-(1-x^2)]=0$$
Simplifying,
$$(1-x^2)(1+2x^2+x^4-1+x^2)=0$$
$$(1-x^2)(x^4+3x^2)=0$$
Factoring,
$$(1-x)(1+x)x^2(x^2+3)=0$$
From here it is easy to see that the roots are $1,-1,0$.

When you are trying to divide with $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ you are killing the possibility of $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ to be $0$ because denominator cannot be $0$. So the solution $±1$ gets
eliminated when you are solving by your method.
